# I am not getting Agree and Setup magento when trying to install magento2

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I have been trying to install Magento from a day or 2 in windows 10 using xampp.I downloaded the Magento zip file from the website and unzipped it in htdocs folder. I also created a database name magento. Whenever I try to install magento by going to localhost/magento It doesn't show Agree and setup magento.
[Magento setup image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ldyb.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be an issue of system cookies, so you should try in Incognito mode, maybe your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

after Magento 2.4 release, there is no UI based installation, so you have to install Magento with CLI
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-install.html

check this might help

or

follow these steps :

1.Download and Install Xampp

2.Download and Install Elasticsearch run

3.Download Magento 2

4. Move Magento 2 Folder and Elasticserach folder to xampp's htdocs folder.

5.Elasticsearch Just for Check http://localhost:9200/

6. Edit Gd2.php file [\vendor\magento\framework\Image\Adapter]: Add " && !file_exists($filename)" part; Around 90 line
7. Edit di.xml file [\app\etc]: find and change word "Symlink" to "copy";
8. Edit Validator.php file [\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template\File]: $realPath = str_replace('\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
9. Create Database
10. php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://localhost/magento" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="dbmagento" --db-user="root" --db-password="" --admin-firstname="admin" --admin-lastname="admin" --admin-email="user@example.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin123" --use-rewrites="1" --backend-frontname="admin"

( Do not turn off elasticsearch / Install take too much time So Please Wait )

11.php bin/magento indexer:reindex

12.php bin/magento setup:upgrade

13.php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

14.php bin/magento cache:flush

15.Fix Two Factor Auth login admin
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth

Comment: I will surely try it .